# Converse Chebyshev inequality

Tags: inequality

The problem (and also the author´s solution):

[image]

Of course I understand the derivation of the inequality etc. but I don´t see how this proves, that there is at least one entry of x with absolute value at least equal to the RMS value of the vector x. All the entries of x are in absolute value less than a. The RMS value is also less than a -> I dont see how this proves the point, the order of RMS and any given entry is not given by this.

Comment: So suppose that $RMS=a$ and all the entries are  $\lt a$: you get a contradiction that $RMS\lt a$

Comment: I get that. All entries are (in absolute value) less than a. For example, if a = 10, then each entry may be from the open interval (-10,10). This is our assumption based on which the inequality rms(x) < a is derived. So yes, from the fact that all entries are less than a, it follows that rms(x) < a. However, I still cannot see how this tells us anything about how there must be "at least one entry of x with absolute value equal to its RMS value". rms(x) must be less than a but so do the entries - what if rms(x) <a, and each entry is < a, but still rms(x) is greater than each entry?

Comment: I'm stuck at the exact problem!